# Perform a string split under a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a list of strings that I want to split but only if it does contain a certain string. For example say I have these strings:

```
'Take a look at this text: It is recommended to',
'Take a look at this text: blah blah blah'
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
'It is recommended to',
'Take a look at this text: blah blah blah'
```

I want to only remove the `'Take a look at this text: '` if we also have `'It is recommended to'`.

I tried this:

```
if df['resolution_modified'].str.contains('It is recommended to ') == False:
    if df['resolution_modified'].str.contains('Take a look at this text: '):
        df['resolution_modified'] = df['resolution_modified'].str.split(':').str[0]
return df
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because you cannot compare an array to Boolean. Instead, you should create an array representing the Boolean mask for your condition and use that to index your data.

```
I want to only remove the 'Take a look at this text: ' if we also have 'It is recommended to'.
```

```py
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": ['Take a look at this text: It is recommended to', 'Take a look at this text: blah blah blah']
})
​
contains_mask = df['col'].str.contains("It is recommended to", regex=False) # turn off regex to save time
​
df.loc[contains_mask,"col"] = df.loc[contains_mask, 'col'].str.split(":").str[1]
df
col
0   It is recommended to
1   Take a look at this text: blah blah blah
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct. If the string is like this 'Take a look at this text: It is recommended to' then you should delete the Take a look at this text: and have the It is recommended to part

Comment: Good catch. Ive updated it. You should grab the index at element 1 from each list, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str.replace` here for a regex option:

```
df['resolution_modified'] = df['resolution_modified']
                               .str.replace('^.*?:\s*(It is recommended to)$', '\\1')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use np.where:

```
df['resolution_modified'] = np.where(df['resolution_modified'].str.contains('It is recommended to'),
                                    df['resolution_modified'].str.replace('Take a look at this text: ', '', np.nan), 
                                     df['resolution_modified'])
```

input:

```
resolution_modified
0   Take a look at this text: It is recommended to
1   Take a look at this text: blah blah blah
```

output:

```
resolution_modified
0   It is recommended to
1   Take a look at this text: blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='Take a look at this text: It is recommended to'
ind=s.find(":")
list=[s[0:ind],s[ind+1:]]
print(list)
```

Output:

```
['Take a look at this text', ' It is recommended to']
```

i think it is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can also using apply

```
pandas = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Take a look at this text: It is recommended to','Take a look at this text: blah blah blah']})
pandas['value'] = pandas['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split(': ')[1] if x.split(': ')[1]=='It is recommended to' else np.nan)
```

here the result

```
A                                                 value
Take a look at this text: It is recommended to    It is recommended to
Take a look at this text: blah blah blah          NaN
```

Comment: You  should not be returning a NaN it should be just Take a look at this text: blah blah blah

Comment: oh sorry, i miss that. you can return the `else np.nan` with `else x` then.